Does anyone know of any sources on the evolution of the four p'sukim added onto the end of Shir Ha'ma'alos before bentshing (Tehilas, etc.)?
Does anyone know of any sources on the evolution of the four p'sukim added onto the end of Shir Ha'ma'alos before bentshing (Tehilas, etc.)?
The 4 verses seem to come from completely different areas of Tanach. How, when and why these were chosen seems a mystery. Anyone know of any source?

I’ve heard from a few rabbis that they are very against saying these pesukim because the pesukim are anti Zionist. Their argument is that Shir Hamaalot is all about returning to Zion and whatnot, but then these pesukim, which are simply praise of Gd, were added on by anti zionists as a way to change the theme from Return of Zion to just praise of Hashem. So perhaps these were added recently during the founding of the State

It does indeed appear to be a mystery.  There is an answer here https://www.yeshiva.co/ask/5227 by Rabbi Ari Shvat where he says (in part, emphasis added by me):
The custom to add those four psukim from assorted places in Tíhilim at the end of Shir HaMaíalot before benching, is found among Jews from Germany, commonly referred to as Yekkim. There is no basis found in the sources (not even achronim) for this, and even the reason is unknown. All I found is a current source, where R. Shmuel Gelbard of Petach Tikva, Otzar Taíamei haMinhagim, who also found no rationale, creatively suggests that each of the verses correspond to one of the four brachot in the benching.

If you like my answer, please consider accepting it. Otherwise, please comment on how it can be improved.

There is a 17-page article by Rabbi Zvi Ron at https://hakirah.org/vol28Ron.pdf that I found after I posted the question.
